# linear combination of certain complex numbers leads to ortogonality

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

Please help me, sorry if it is dumb or too easy, but I'm really stuck.

I need to prove that: Let $X$ be an inner product space and $x,y\in X$.
If $\|x+\alpha y\|=\|x-\alpha y\|\:\forall \alpha\in \mathbb{C}$, then $\langle x,y\rangle=0$.

Expanding $\|x+\alpha y\|=\|x-\alpha y\|$, I got $\overline{\alpha}\langle x,y\rangle+\alpha\langle y,x\rangle=0$

The hint says I should take $\alpha=1,i$, so:

For $\alpha=1$,
\begin{equation}\label{e1}
\langle x,y\rangle +\langle y,x\rangle =0\quad (1)
\end{equation}

For $\alpha=i$,
\begin{equation}\label{e2}
-i\langle x,y\rangle +i\langle y,x\rangle =0 \quad (2)
\end{equation}

Subtracting (1) from (2) I got
\begin{align*}
(1+i)(-\langle x,y\rangle+\langle y,x\rangle)&=0\\
\langle x,y\rangle=\overline{\langle x,y\rangle}
\end{align*}

So $\langle x,y\rangle\in \mathbb{R}$, but I don't know how to get that $\langle x,y\rangle=0$.
I'm stuck there.\

I tried to add (1) and (2), getting
\begin{align*}
(1-i)\langle x,y\rangle+\overline{(1-i)\langle x,y\rangle}=0\\
\Rightarrow Re((1-i)\langle x,y\rangle)=0
\end{align*}
but also I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Divide (2) by $i$ before you subtract. Or add.

Comment: Thank you!! I got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using conjugate symmetry property of inner product, we can slightly expand from what you have obtained:

$$
\begin{aligned}
0 &=
\overline{\alpha}\langle x,y\rangle+\alpha \langle y,x\rangle \\
&=
\overline{\alpha}\langle x,y\rangle+\alpha \overline{\langle x,y\rangle} \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Since the expression holds for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\langle x,y\rangle\in\mathbb{C}$, we can choose $\alpha = \langle x,y\rangle$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
0 &=
\overline{\langle x,y\rangle}\langle x,y\rangle +
\langle x,y\rangle\overline{\langle x,y\rangle} \\
&=
2\left|\langle x,y\rangle\right|^{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thank you!! it would never have occurred that idea to me and it's really smooth :D 
It it a better way of doing it instead of the hint given in my book :D
Thank you a lot

Comment: @AHexe no problem! If you find it helpful hope you don't mind to upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend squaring both sides of the equation, and then using that for any vector $z$, $$||z||^2 = z^T \bar{z}.$$ Feel free to ask if you need additional hints!

Comment: Thanks :D and sorry, I forgot to mention that $x,y\in X$ where $X$ is an inner product space. So I think $\|z\|=z^{T}\overline{z}$ couldn't be helpful? I'm confused